# If someone is using multiple Illusion effects, how do they layer?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Say if someone is using a Hat of Disguise, the Rogue ACF Mimic, Alter Self Spell, and a Disguise Self Spell?

Which effect would be seen?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to say here, Alter Self spell is not an illusion, but real physical change (though mostly a superficial one). So your new look would be your real sensory quality and it is what would be changed (see below) with illusion magic.

Now, illusion magic starts. Hat of Disguise and Mimic both emulate Disguise Self Spell. Disguise Self represents [Glamer subschool](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#glamer) of Illusion school of magic and works as follows:

> A glamer spell changes a subject’s sensory qualities, making it look, feel, taste, smell, or sound like something else, or even seem to disappear.

That means, unlike [Figment](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#figment) spells, [Glamer](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#glamer) spells don't produce images which could swarm around you if you use several of them. They "set" your sensory qualities to something, so, an effect which comes last would be seen.

Previous illusion effects in your example are still there, but subsequently [made irrelevant](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#combiningMagicalEffects) by later ones. Alter Self, in its turn, isn't irrelevant, but only disguised by illusions. If you, for example, got claw attacks from your new form (say, lizardfolk), they are peretty much available even if you disguise yourself as a human later.